# Converting TimeofDay in vb.net to minutes

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetime

Good day, I need help guys in VB 2015 and MySQL Workbench. I'm creating a Time In Out program. my goal is to check if the user has already time in for the past 5 minutes if so it will turn as time Out if not it will time In.

```
messagebox.show(TimeOfDay)
```

TimeOfDay returns the current time with 12 Hours Format like this:

```
02:30:23 PM
```

So I want to convert this to minutes and later on, I want to get a difference from it to determine if 5 minutes has passed.. I will appreciate any help or comments and suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: you haven't search pretty hard. Where's your code?

Answer (score 2):

TotalMinutes is a TimeSpan property which gets you the resulting amount of minutes, so...

```
Dim first = DateTime.Now
...
Dim last = DateTime.Now    
Dim minuteSpan as TimeSpan = first.Subtract(last)
Dim minutes = minuteSpan.TotalMinutes
```

Comment: Yeah...quiet simplier than mine...Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy.Firstly do this :

```
Private dt = DateTime.Now
```

Then,use integers

```
Dim HrtoMinute as integer = dt.Hour * 60

Dim ttlminutes as integer = HrtoMinute + dt.Minute

'Now,to convert seconds into minutes

dim sctndstomnts as integer = CSng(dt.Second) / 60

'Now for end result

Dim result as integer = ttlminutes + sctndstomnts
```

That's all i guess